# VBA range problem running macro takes too long

Tags: excel, vba

**Some quick information:**
My code checks when a value is changed and then executes the code which you will find below. The outcome strings goes in column R.

**The problem goes as follows:**
When one value is changed the code runs and does all the rows again which demands too much computing work and time.

**What I want:**
I only want, when a value is changed in a row that only that row where the value is changed the value in column R will be replaced or filled in.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C2:P150"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        'If you add (an)other row(s) edit the range above
        Call DeleteR2R150
        'If you add (an)other row(s) edit the range above
        Call SampleMacro1
    End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteR2R150()
    Range("R2:R150").Select
    'If you add (an)other row(s) edit the range above
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub


Sub SampleMacro1()

    ' Get the last row
    Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    startRow = 2
    lastRow = Sheet4.Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = startRow To lastRow

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in C column, then append next sentence
    If Sheet4.Range("C" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = "? De privacy policy is niet transparant."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("C" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = "? De privacy policy is gedeeltelijk transparant."
    End If

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in D column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("D" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De inhoud is grotendeels onbegrijpelijk wegens juridisch opgebouwde teksten."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("D" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De inhoud is grotendeels begrijpelijk, maar sommige woorden hebben duidelijkere synoniemen."
    End If

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in E column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("E" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De privacy policy is hier niet aanwezig."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("E" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De privacy policy was te vinden onder een andere naam."
    End If

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in F column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("F" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Deze policy is allesbehalve beknopt geschreven."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("F" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Deze policy is deels beknopt geschreven."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in G column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("G" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De verwerkingsverantwoordelijke is niet aanwezig op de privacy policy."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("G" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Een deel van de gegevens van de verwerkingsverantwoordelijke is niet aanwezig op de privacy policy."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in H column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("H" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Welke gegevens ze verzamelen is niet aanwezig."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("H" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Welke gegevens ze verzamelen is matig aanwezig."
    End If

     'If there's Nee/Matig in I column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("I" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De manier waarop ze gegevens verzamelen is niet omschreven."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("I" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De manier waarop ze gegevens verzamelen is matig omschreven."
    End If

     'If there's Nee/Matig in J column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("J" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uiteindelijke doeleinden voor de gegevens zijn nergens terug te vinden."
    ElseIf Sheet4.Range("J" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uiteindelijke doeleinden voor de gegevens zijn matig terug te vinden."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in K column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("K" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Met wie de gegevens gedeeld worden staat niet in de privacy policy."
     ElseIf Sheet4.Range("K" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Met wie de gegevens gedeeld worden staat matig in de privacy policy."
    End If


    'If there's Nee/Matig in L column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("L" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Nergens wordt er gesproken over hoe ze gegevens beschermen."
     ElseIf Sheet4.Range("L" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Er wordt matig gesproken over hoe ze gegevens beschermen."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in M column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("M" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Over de bewaartermijn van de gegevens wordt er niet gesproken."
     ElseIf Sheet4.Range("M" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Over de bewaartermijn van de gegevens wordt er matig gesproken."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in N column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("N" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De verschillende rechten die personen hebben is hier niet omschreven."
     ElseIf Sheet4.Range("N" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De verschillende rechten die personen hebben is hier matig omschreven."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in O column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("O" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De gegevens worden wel/niet verwerkt buiten de EER maar dit staat niet in de privacy policy."
     ElseIf Sheet4.Range("O" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De gegevens worden wel/niet verwerkt buiten de EER maar dit staat matig in de privacy policy."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in P column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet4.Range("P" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uitleg over de geautomatiseerd besluitvorming en het al dan niet gebruik ervan staat niet in de privacy policy."
     ElseIf Sheet4.Range("P" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value = Sheet4.Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uitleg over de geautomatiseerd besluitvorming en het al dan niet gebruik ervan staat matig in de privacy policy."
    End If


    Next

End Sub
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: PS. Why not use direct commands like `Range("R2:R150").ClearContents` but instead choose to use `.Select` and `Selection` which slow down the code with updating the worksheet and use up memory?   Also, replace `Range("R" & i)` with `Range("R1").Cells(i,1)` which is also faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C2:P150"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then 'It s better to use Target.Count = 1 in oder to trigget the code only if one cell is change to avoid errors
        'If you add (an)other row(s) edit the range above
        Call DeleteR2R150
        'If you add (an)other row(s) edit the range above
        Call SampleMacro1
    End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteR2R150()

    Range("R2:R150").ClearContents  'It s a better idea to specify worksheet.
    'If you add (an)other row(s) edit the range above

End Sub


Sub SampleMacro1()

    ' Get the last row
    Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    startRow = 2

    With thisworkbok.Worksheets("Sheet4") 'Use with statement to avoid reputation

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disable event to avoid code trigger each time you change something

        For i = startRow To lastRow

            ' If there's Nee/Matig in C column, then append next sentence
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = "? De privacy policy is niet transparant."
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = "? De privacy policy is gedeeltelijk transparant."
            End If

            ' If there's Nee/Matig in D column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("D" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De inhoud is grotendeels onbegrijpelijk wegens juridisch opgebouwde teksten."
            ElseIf .Range("D" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De inhoud is grotendeels begrijpelijk, maar sommige woorden hebben duidelijkere synoniemen."
            End If

            ' If there's Nee/Matig in E column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("E" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De privacy policy is hier niet aanwezig."
            ElseIf .Range("E" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De privacy policy was te vinden onder een andere naam."
            End If

            ' If there's Nee/Matig in F column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("F" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Deze policy is allesbehalve beknopt geschreven."
            ElseIf .Range("F" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Deze policy is deels beknopt geschreven."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in G column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("G" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De verwerkingsverantwoordelijke is niet aanwezig op de privacy policy."
            ElseIf .Range("G" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Een deel van de gegevens van de verwerkingsverantwoordelijke is niet aanwezig op de privacy policy."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in H column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("H" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Welke gegevens ze verzamelen is niet aanwezig."
            ElseIf .Range("H" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Welke gegevens ze verzamelen is matig aanwezig."
            End If

             'If there's Nee/Matig in I column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("I" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De manier waarop ze gegevens verzamelen is niet omschreven."
            ElseIf .Range("I" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De manier waarop ze gegevens verzamelen is matig omschreven."
            End If

             'If there's Nee/Matig in J column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("J" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uiteindelijke doeleinden voor de gegevens zijn nergens terug te vinden."
            ElseIf .Range("J" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uiteindelijke doeleinden voor de gegevens zijn matig terug te vinden."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in K column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("K" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Met wie de gegevens gedeeld worden staat niet in de privacy policy."
             ElseIf .Range("K" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Met wie de gegevens gedeeld worden staat matig in de privacy policy."
            End If


            'If there's Nee/Matig in L column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("L" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Nergens wordt er gesproken over hoe ze gegevens beschermen."
             ElseIf .Range("L" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Er wordt matig gesproken over hoe ze gegevens beschermen."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in M column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("M" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Over de bewaartermijn van de gegevens wordt er niet gesproken."
             ElseIf .Range("M" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Over de bewaartermijn van de gegevens wordt er matig gesproken."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in N column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("N" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De verschillende rechten die personen hebben is hier niet omschreven."
             ElseIf .Range("N" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De verschillende rechten die personen hebben is hier matig omschreven."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in O column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("O" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De gegevens worden wel/niet verwerkt buiten de EER maar dit staat niet in de privacy policy."
             ElseIf .Range("O" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De gegevens worden wel/niet verwerkt buiten de EER maar dit staat matig in de privacy policy."
            End If

            'If there's Nee/Matig in P column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
            If .Range("P" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uitleg over de geautomatiseerd besluitvorming en het al dan niet gebruik ervan staat niet in de privacy policy."
             ElseIf .Range("P" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
                .Range("R" & i).Value = .Range("R" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De uitleg over de geautomatiseerd besluitvorming en het al dan niet gebruik ervan staat matig in de privacy policy."
            End If

        Next i

        Application.EnableEvents = True 'Eanble events

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Variable i not defined?

Comment: @Batty You need to `Dim i As Long` before its first usage. Every variable needs to be declared before you can use it.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, thanks for the answer! The code is running but still doesn't do what I want.

Only the rowvalue that is changed should trigger the event to edit the outcome in column R in that same row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to disable event triggers while making your changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C2:P150"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call DeleteR2R150
        Call SampleMacro1
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```